# Count all words in comma separated strings per group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

i would like to count schools(separated by commas) from the data frame given below.

Dataframe:

```
State    Counties    Schools_list
S1       C1          GradeA,GradeB,GradeC
S1       C1          GradeD
S2       C1          GradeA,GradeB
S2       C2          GradeC
S3       C2          GradeA,GradeB
S3       C3          GradeC,GradeD
```

Output:

```
State          Schools_count
S1             4
S2             3
S3             4
```

How to count comma separated list of schools from last column by State.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your code (even if you are not proud of it, don't be shy). We won't write the code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution here would be to count the commas:

```
df['Schools_list'].str.count(',').add(1).groupby(df.State).sum()

State
S1    4
S2    3
S3    4
Name: Schools_list, dtype: int64
```

Note that, once you have counted the commas, group on the State name to get the count by state.

As a DataFrame,

```
(df['Schools_list'].str.count(',')
                   .add(1)
                   .groupby(df.State)
                   .sum()
                   .reset_index(name='Schools_count'))

  State  Schools_count
0    S1              4
1    S2              3
2    S3              4
```

---

You can also split on comma and find the length of the lists created, but this is a bit slower.

```
df['Schools_list'].str.split(',+').str.len().groupby(df.State).sum()

State
S1    4
S2    3
S3    4
Name: Schools_list, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Second snippet gives correct output. however count is displayed as float. I need it to be int.

Comment: @NirajBhatt `(df['Schools_list'].str.count(',')
                   .add(1)
                   .groupby(df.State)
                   .sum().astype(int)
                   .reset_index(name='Schools_count'))`

Comment: @NirajBhatt OR `df['Schools_list'].str.split(',+').str.len().groupby(df.State).sum().astype(int).reset_index(name='Schools_count')`